# Как написать SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Привет!
Необходимо написать запрос, который подсчитывает количество выходных дней, а потом выдает день, в   котором количество выходных дней "пересекает экватор"
Другими словами, необходимо внутри каждого года найти первый выходной день, когда   количество  прошедших выходных дней, включая текущий,   составляет  как минимум половину от количества  всех выходных дней.

Таблица выглядит вот так: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я написал такой запрос, который считает количество выходных для каждой даты и выводит их в отдельную переменную

```
SELECT
calendar_dt,
year_no
holiday_flg,
SUM(holiday_flg) OVER (PARTITION BY year_no ORDER BY calendar_dt) as holiday_count
FROM asql.calendar
LIMIT 1000
```

Дальше я хотел через case написать проверку по пресечению экватора, и в случае верного утверждения выводить дату этого события. 
Однако я не очень понимаю, как я могу оперировать значением holiday_count, пока оно у меня еще не создано. Иными словами, мне для сравнения нужно значение holiday_count на момент 31/12/200* . Но как мне его получить, не совершив запрос я не понимаю.

Comment: `SUM(holiday_flg) OVER (PARTITION BY year_no)` даст как раз общую сумму по году. значит нужна точка, где `SUM(holiday_flg) OVER (PARTITION BY year_no) / SUM(holiday_flg) OVER (PARTITION BY year_no ORDER BY calendar_dt)` станет меньше 2.

Answer (score 2):

Оконные функции sum/count с предложеннием `order by` в `over()` дают текущую сумму, а без предложения `order by` дают как раз сумму/количество для группы целиком, т.е. на момент ее завершения (31.12.20xx).

```
select *
  from (
   select *,
          count(1) over(partition by year_no) as a_cnt,
          count(1) over(partition by year_no order by calendar_dt) c_cnt
     from calendar
    where holyday_flg=1
  ) A
 where (a_cnt+1)/2=c_cnt
```

Целочисленное деление (с округлением вниз) количества выходных +1 на 2 дает фактически порядковый номер первого выходного перевалившего экватор. Остается только сравнить этот номер с текущим номером выходного.